# What are the top find utilities for Mac, other than EasyFind and Finder?

Tags: macos

What are the top find utilities for Mac, other than EasyFind and Finder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out [Find Any File](http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/index.html) or just `find` on the command line? These are the file finding applications I use when Spotlight won't cut it.